# Select no XML dinâmico retornando todos os valores possíveis dentro das tags - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

eu gostaria de saber se é possível fazer um select em um XML trazendo todos os resultados possíveis dentro do select e armazenado em uma variável

XML:

```
<Nome>@PartyId</Nome><Nome>@CallId</Nome>
```

A tag `<Nome>` sempre irá vir, porém eu preciso armazenar todos os valores que vier dentro dessas tags concatenando eles em uma variável assim :

```
DECLARE X VARCHAR(MAX)
SET X = '@PartyId @CallId'
```

Comment: sim é possível usando `nodes` para filtrar

Comment: poderia me dar algum exemplo por favor ? @RicardoPontual